# creating a default database in mysql using dockerfile

Tags: mysql, docker

Im using this [tutum-docker-mysql](https://github.com/tutumcloud/tutum-docker-mysql) dockerfile, to get up and running with a docker image with mysql installed in it,the docker file creates a user with the name root and no password, what i need is to add  something like this to the dockerfile:

```
RUN mysql -uroot -p""  &&  mysql create database test;
```

So when I build an image from the docker file, the database should already be there.

Comment: What happens when you try this?

Comment: i tried few commands, and got diff errors, i tried mysql -uroot "create database test", and the error is :ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Comment: Also tried mysqld -uroot -p"" "create database test", and the error is :140710 10:12:28 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.

Comment: And have also tried RUN /usr/bin/mysqld_safe sleep 5 && mysql -uroot -e  "create database test;" which is similar to the query in the create_db file in the same repository, this time the error is :140710 10:15:24 mysqld_safe Can't log to error log and syslog at the same time.  Remove all --log-error configuration options for --syslog to take effect.

Comment: How does your Dockerfile look?

Comment: This is the exact Dockerfile that i use:https://github.com/tutumcloud/tutum-docker-mysql/blob/master/Dockerfile      but have this extra line :RUN /usr/bin/mysqld_safe sleep 5 && mysql -uroot -e  "create database test;"

Comment: So you downloaded and changed the Dockerfile or what were you actually doing? If you would provide all information in your question, someone might be able to help you sooner. E.g., showing your Dockerfile and how you build your image.

Comment: Hi Behe, thanks alot for your responses,here is the exact question,I want to use this docker file: https://github.com/tutumcloud/tutum-docker-mysql/blob/master/Dockerfile, to create an image with mysql installed in it, i create the image simply by writing sudo docker build -t="test/test" . , and everything is fine, except one thing, i need to add something to this file, to create a databased called test, inside the mysql, so when i run the image, to use the mysql, it has a database called test in it, and i don't need to create it mannually, thats it.

Answer (score 11):

I was able to accomplish the goal of adding a database to the tutum-docker-mysql image by doing the following.

```
git clone https://github.com/tutumcloud/tutum-docker-mysql.git
cd tutum-docker-mysql
vi create_mysql_admin_user.sh
```

Inside of that .sh file I added a line, right below the two "mysql -uroot" lines that are already there.  I simply added:

```
mysql -uroot -e "create database test;"
```

After that change to that .sh file, I simply built the docker image.

```
docker build -t tutum/mysql .
```

After the docker image was built, I could run it with something like:

```
docker run -d -p 3307:3306 tutum/mysql
```

Once the container is running, you need to know the password to use and the ip address of the container.  To get the password you simply do

```
docker logs 2976a81f1a9b19787d9bde893c831b7e6586d7c8391ccd222ad29b02c282d896
```

But of course use the container id, that was returned from the "docker run" command above.  Now that you have the password, you need the ip address.  I get that by doing.

```
docker inspect 2976a81f1a9b19787d9bde893c831b7e6586d7c8391ccd222ad29b02c282d896
```

And looking at the "Gateway" address.  With the password and the ip address I was then able to do this mysql command from OUTSIDE of the container.

```
mysql -uadmin -pJcM5FCphMOp4 -h172.17.42.1 -P3307
```

Where the ip address and the password are the values I got from the previous two docker commands.  After that command has run, I can then issue a "show databases" command with the following results.

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| test               |
+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

I fought for a while trying it by modifying the Dockerfile.  I think it might be possible, but after a while, I found the above solution a lot quicker and simpler.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass ON_CREATE_DB env parameter on container startup.
Example from [tutum README.md](https://github.com/tutumcloud/mysql/blob/master/README.md#creating-a-database-on-container-creation)

`docker run -d -p 3306:3306 -e ON_CREATE_DB="newdatabase" tutum/mysql`